# How to fetch AccessToken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oidc-client

I am using the following plugin( @axa-fr/react-oidc-context ) in React to enable authentication with AzureAd. Now I need to access the access_token in ApolloClient after the authentication is done. I am not sure how to fetch the access_token in non react component like ApolloClient.

Here is what i am doing.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthenticationProvider, withOidcSecure } from "@axa-fr/react-oidc-context";
import { IDENTITY_CONFIG } from "./utils/configuration";
// components
import Layout from "./Layout";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthenticationProvider configuration={IDENTITY_CONFIG}>
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={withOidcSecure(Layout)} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </AuthenticationProvider>
  );
}
```

Layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import client from "./apollo";

import Dashboard from "./pages/dashboard";

function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Layout);
```

apollo.js

```
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { ApolloLink, split } from "apollo-link";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";
import { getMainDefinition } from "apollo-utilities";

import { useReactOidc } from "@axa-fr/react-oidc-context";

const { oidcUser } = useReactOidc();

console.log(oidcUser.access_token)

const httpUri = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
  ? process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
  : "https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io";
const wsUri = httpUri.replace(
  /^https?/,
  process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "dev" ? "ws" : "wss"
);

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: httpUri
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: wsUri,
  options: {
    lazy: true,
    reconnect: true
    // connectionParams: () => {
    //   return { headers: { Authorization: getAuthHeader() } };
    // }
  }
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  //   const auth = getAuthHeader()

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers
      //   Authorization: auth,
    }
  };
});

const terminatingLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
    return kind === "OperationDefinition" && operation === "subscription";
  },
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink)
);

const link = ApolloLink.from([terminatingLink]);
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache
});

export default client;
```

I am trying to pull the access token in apollo.js file, but it's throwing error where it says I cannot access React Hooks in Non React component.

Comment: which part of your code is attempting to fetch an access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the token info is getting stored in sessionStorage after authentication, i was able to pull access_token info from session storage and assigned as Authorization Header to my ApolloClient.

Please let me know if there is a better solution.

Update:

Instead of getting token for session storage, we can use useReactOidc to get the access_token as pass as props to Apollo Client. Please see the updated code.

Layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { useReactOidc } from "@axa-fr/react-oidc-context";
import client from "./apollo";

import Dashboard from "./pages/dashboard";

function Layout(props) {
  const { oidcUser } = useReactOidc();

  return (
    <>
      <ApolloProvider client={client(oidcUser.access_token)}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Layout);
```

apollo.js

```
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { ApolloLink, split } from "apollo-link";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";
import { getMainDefinition } from "apollo-utilities";

const httpUri = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
  ? process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
  : "http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql";
const wsUri = httpUri.replace(
  /^https?/,
  process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "dev" ? "ws" : "wss"
);

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: httpUri
});

const wsLink = token =>
  new WebSocketLink({
    uri: wsUri,
    options: {
      lazy: true,
      reconnect: true,
      connectionParams: () => {
        return { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } };
      }
    }
  });

const authLink = token =>
  setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    };
  });

const terminatingLink = token =>
  split(
    ({ query }) => {
      const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
      return kind === "OperationDefinition" && operation === "subscription";
    },
    wsLink(token),
    authLink(token).concat(httpLink)
  );

const link = token => ApolloLink.from([terminatingLink(token)]);
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = token =>
  new ApolloClient({
    link: link(token),
    cache: cache
  });

export default client;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used this library before, but it looks like it's using a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to pass props to the wrapped component that you're passing into `withOidcSecure`. You should be able to access whatever data is being provided through the `props` in your `Layout` component.  Try using `console.log(props)` inside of it and see what it returns, I'm not sure exactly what data's being passed down.